# Bokeh: How to click and drag to display displacement between points

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to be able to click and drag between two points on my graph and display the change in position between points and display a line connecting the two points. How can I go about approaching this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can realize it with JS callback like this (Bokeh v1.3.0):

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Div, Row
from bokeh.events import *

source = ColumnDataSource({'x': [], 'y': []})

p = figure(plot_width = 900)
lines = [p.line(np.arange(10), np.random.random(10)) for i in range(3)]
lilne = p.line('x', 'y', line_color = 'red', line_dash = 'dashed', source = source)
div = Div(text='')

callback_tap = '''
if (true === Bokeh.drawing) {
    Bokeh.drawing = false
}
else {
    if (!Bokeh.drawing) {
        src.data = {'x':[], 'y':[]}        
        src.change.emit()
    }

    src.data['x'].push(cb_obj.x)
    src.data['y'].push(cb_obj.y)

    Bokeh.drawing = true
    Bokeh.sx_start = cb_obj.sx
    Bokeh.x_start = cb_obj.x
}'''

callback_mousemove = '''
if (Bokeh.drawing) {  
    if (src.data['x'].length > 1) {
        src.data['x'].pop()
        src.data['y'].pop()   
    }

    src.data['x'].push(cb_obj.x)
    src.data['y'].push(cb_obj.y)
    src.change.emit()

    div.text = 'Distance: ' + Math.round(cb_obj.sx - Bokeh.sx_start) + ' px' + ' (' + (Math.round((cb_obj.x - Bokeh.x_start) * 100) / 100) + ' units)'
}'''

p.js_on_event('tap', CustomJS(args = {'src': source}, code = callback_tap))
p.js_on_event('mousemove', CustomJS(args = {'src': source, 'div': div}, code = callback_mousemove))

show(Row(p, div))
```

The first click on the plot starts the line, the next click ends it.

[image]

Or if you prefer a tooltip-like div appearance you could use this a  little bit more complicated code which dynamically adds a tooltip div:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.events import *

source = ColumnDataSource({'x': [], 'y': []})

p = figure(plot_width = 900)
lines = [p.line(np.arange(10), np.random.random(10)) for i in range(3)]
line = p.line('x', 'y', line_color = 'red', line_dash = 'dashed', source = source)

callback_tap = '''

if (typeof custom_tooltip == 'undefined') {
        custom_tooltip = document.createElement('div');
        custom_tooltip.setAttribute('id','tooltip_div');
        custom_tooltip.style = 'position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 9999; border:1px solid black; padding: 10px; background: white; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px'
        document.body.prepend(custom_tooltip);  
}        

if (true === Bokeh.drawing) {
    Bokeh.drawing = false
}
else {
    if (!Bokeh.drawing) {
        src.data = {'x':[], 'y':[]}        
        src.change.emit()
    }

    src.data['x'].push(cb_obj.x)
    src.data['y'].push(cb_obj.y)

    Bokeh.drawing = true
    Bokeh.sx_start = cb_obj.sx
    Bokeh.x_start = cb_obj.x
    Bokeh.sy_start = cb_obj.sy
    Bokeh.y_start = cb_obj.y  
}'''

callback_mousemove = '''
function print(...args) {
    for (i in args) {
        console.log(args[i])
    }
}

if (Bokeh.drawing) {  
    if (src.data['x'].length > 1) {
        src.data['x'].pop()
        src.data['y'].pop()   
    }

    src.data['x'].push(cb_obj.x)
    src.data['y'].push(cb_obj.y)
    src.change.emit()

    tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip_div')
    tooltip.style.left = cb_obj.sx + 30 + 'px'
    tooltip.style.top = cb_obj.sy + 10 + 'px'
    tooltip.innerHTML = 'Distance X: ' + Math.round(cb_obj.sx - Bokeh.sx_start) + ' px' + ' (units): ' + (Math.round((cb_obj.x - Bokeh.x_start) * 100) / 100) + ' units' + 
                        '<br />' +
                        'Distance Y: ' + Math.round(cb_obj.sy - Bokeh.sy_start) + ' px' + ' (units): ' + (Math.round((cb_obj.y - Bokeh.y_start) * 100) / 100) + ' units' 

}'''

p.js_on_event('tap', CustomJS(args = {'src': source, }, code = callback_tap))
p.js_on_event('mousemove', CustomJS(args = {'src': source, }, code = callback_mousemove))

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: This is actually really great! One question with the tooltip though. Would it be possible to disable the tool? Perhaps by right clicking?

Comment: Looks awesome, exactly what i was after. But not working for me: I get an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: custom_tooltip is not defined
    at M.eval (eval at get func (bokeh-2.4.2.min.js:424:252)` in my browser console...maybe it's broken in the latest bokeh...

Comment: Unfortunately this code was made for v1.3.0 and your version is v2.4.2 which may not be compatible. Sorry, but it is impossible to keep all hundreds of posts up to date with each Bokeh release. Just try to debug to understand the errors and see how you can change the code then post it here. Thanks